# Use System.Type in WCF Datacontract

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm building a distributed (client-server are both .NET) .NET-Application using `WCF`. As you can see in the code below I'd like to use System.Type in one of my DataContracs to send types of parameters. However I always get an Exception when I do it like this. All other stuff is working, means when I remove the System.Type property it's working well.

```
[DataContract]
  public class PluginParametersItemDto
  {
     [DataMember]
     public String Name { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public Type Type { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public Object Value { get; set; }

     public PluginParametersItemDto(String name, Type type, Object value)
     {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Value = value;
     }
  }
```

Anyone an Idea how I could pass generic type definitions to my client? Or is it even possible?

Comment: Looks like you can't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500870/serialize-generic-type-over-wcf-service
Since under the cover WCF is sending XML across the wire, the most generic type would be XML, or maybe just a message.

Comment: Could you omit the type from the contract and set it in your constructor with "this.Type = typeof(value)"?

Comment: Workaround with typeof() is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is broken fundamentally.

You can not send a type - you need to send the assembly it is in (which is a byte array). Types are in memory representation - and they may rely on other types.

Now, if you have the assembly on the other side - do not send the type (as you do), but the full type name, then you can instantiate it. But If I read this right and this is a plugin setup, then I think you have a problem that you do not actually have the type on the receiving end - and then things really get a little complicated.

Comment: That sounds obvious. Yes its a plugin setup and I don't have the assembly  on the client's side. On the client's side is a ASP.NET MVC website wher I want to display a form with parameter types from a plugin implementation.  Parameters are properties which are decorated with a specific attribute.

Comment: Then you need to send the name and I would say something like a config, the client then downloads that. I Would pack up the plugin into a zip file- because quite often you will also want o have additional dll's or possible ressource files for download. Remember to have a download location as per windows guidelines and REMBMER SECURITY.

Comment: Okay, seems that I need to completely change my approach. Thank you für your advices.

Answer (score -1):

This is because of default serialization which uses `DataContractSerializer`. Try switching both your client and server to use [NetDataContractSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) which embeds .NET type information. In this case your service won't be compatible with standard web services but as long as you're sure both sides are written in .NET you'll be fine.