# How to call a generic c# web service from vb project

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, generics

Here is an example of my situation:

C# generic function

```
public string Foo<t>(string test)
{
   return test+test.ToString();
}
```

VB

```
webservice.Foo(Of int, "Bar")
```

///^This will error out saying 
"has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments"

Normally when I call a type inferenced function in C# I do something like `Foo<int>()`. However I am unsure how to do it in VB. My searches haven't been fruitful. If someone could lead me where to search for a solution or help me, I would greatly appreciate it!

**---Update ----**

After some more research I found out that you can't have a generic function in as a contract unless it's bounded. If you would like to know more you can click ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500870/serialize-generic-type-over-wcf-servicemarshaling%20rules%20for%20collections.)) Which says the following

"You cannot define WCF contracts that rely on generic type parameters. Generics are specific to .NET, and using them would violate the service-oriented nature of WCF. However, a data contract can include a collection as a data member because WCF offers dedicated marshaling rules for collections." Sleiman

&

"Sleiman is correct, but one can use Bounded Generics as described in [this article](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/05/10/WCF-Serialization-and-Generics.aspx), and you may be able to achieve what you want. This allows you to create a generic type within the service and expose it. But the consumer will not view it as generic as the type is specified in the service operation." Idgorman.

Comment: `<T>` isn't used at all...

Comment: create web service to somewhere and then take a look at the generated code for one of the methods...you should see the answer there

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with WCF. The code you provided is meaningless. You should fix the code to show an actual generic function (where the type parameter is used) to give your question some substance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have a generic function in a WCF service and call it (bounded generics excluded). I go into more detail about it in my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
webservice.Foo(of int)("Bar")
```

Comment: I get the same error "has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments"

Comment: Could you post the WSDL here?

Comment: after some research I found out I couldn't declare a generic WCF function. I have updated my original post. Also you are correct that that's how you do type inference in VB.