# WCF generic property is not mapped in derived class

Tags: wcf

I have:

```
[DataContract]
public class A 
{ 
    [DataMember]
    public int X { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Derived<A>))]
public class Base {}

[DataContract]
public class Derived<T>: Base { 

    [DataMember]
    public T Data {get; set; } 

}
```

Service method returns IEnumerable of Base class containing object of Derived class. 
Auto-generated WCF client retrieves data and correctly detects type and creates instances of the Derived class, but Derived.Data.X is not mapped, i.e. has 0. The soap message received is correct. 
Any ideas why the generic property of the derived class is not correctly mapped from the soap message in the client?

Comment: Did you also try adding `[KnownType(typeof(A))]`?

Comment: Yes, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you to avoid generics in service contracts. SOA world is not friendly with generic type in the service contract. Please look problems reported by others:

[Error when updating service reference.The URI prefix is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468931/error-when-updating-service-reference-the-uri-prefix-is-not-recognized)

[WCF. Service generic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906694/wcf-service-generic-methods)

[WCF generic property is not mapped in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764993/wcf-generic-property-is-not-mapped-in-derived-class)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2a9a2fc6-9e01-4112-8948-4192c516c6e7/how-to-use-generics-in-wcf-service

Comment: Sad but true. However, I would change "SOA world" to "WCF world".

Comment: @empi:  No, it's SOA. How would you describe that generic type using XSD? How would you describe in in the WSDL? There are many OO concepts which do not map to XSD and WSDL so cannot be used in SOA.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: to be precise - I don't expect SOA to handle generics (in xsd, wsdl, etc.). I do expect WCF to handle it behind the scenes. For example I'm not able to expose contract interface IStringFoo : IFoo<string> {}, interface IFoo<T> { T Bar(); }. I think it is a topic for a bigger discussion, but that's what I meant. Bottom line is - don't use generics with WCF.