# Error when updating service reference.The URI prefix is not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a Wcf service that is hosted in the service then a mvc client that connects with tcp.
Got everything working fine until I updated a service and now I cant update the reference on the client side.

This is a service contract

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "Rules", Namespace = "http://api.xxx.com/2013/10/Rules")]
    public interface IRuleContractV1
    {
        [OperationContract(Name="GetRules")]
        PagedData<RuleDTO> GetRules();

        [OperationContract(Name="GetRulePaths")]
        PagedData<Rule_PathDTO> GetRulePaths(int ruleId);
    }
```

Now the second operation contract GetRulePaths is the one that I have added when updating the reference stopped working. If I remove the PagedData and just return a list, then it works. If I copy PagedData class and change the name of it, so that GetRules returns PagedData<> and GetRulePaths PagingData<>. (PagedData is a simple class that holds a totalnumber of items and data as ienumerable).

The error that I get when trying to update the service reference is:
*The URI prefix is not recognized.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8002/SSAPI/mex'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8002/SSAPI/mex'.*

Here is the AppConfig wcf configuration

```
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
...
<services>
<service name="SSService.Wcf.AdminService">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpMexBinding"
          name="mexAdminApi" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="Rules" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpSecureBinding"
          contract="SS.Wcf.Admin.Contracts.IRuleContractV1" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8002/SSAPI" />
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8003/SSAPI" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
...
<bindings>
<netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpSecureBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <message algorithmSuite="Basic256Sha256Rsa15" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
      <mexTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpMexBinding" />
      </mexTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

---

Found the reason, but not sure why this happens. It is my PagedData class that looks like this:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract(Name = "PagedData", Namespace = "http://api.xxx.com/2013/10/types")]
    public class PagedData<T> where T : class
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Container with the actual data that is paged.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name = "Data")]
        public List<T> Data { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Total number of items. 
        /// </summary>
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name = "TotalItems")]
        public long TotalItems { get; set; }
    }
```

If I remove the annotation for data member Data then it works to update the reference.

Comment: I like to see your PagedData implementation..

Comment: Hmmm, didn't know you can expose generic types through the service interface. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: I have added PagedData contract in later edit. Generics as I understand are supported. Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Comment: Even here when Reading on serialization it states that the genric types are supported.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx

Comment: Not getting anywhere with this. Changed it to return a list instead with out parameter of total count. That works for now.

Comment: I got the same stupid error message on a operation contract that had a faultcontract which did not have datacontract anotation on it. Seems to me like this error is: something went to hell and it might be anywhere in your code. Thanks for that.

Comment: @user1540857: Yeah, this error is misleading at best. For future reference: I discovered exactly what was the problem in my case by using `svcutil` from the VS command line, and setting `includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"` for my service. This should dump full error information to the console when things fail.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "WCF Non-HTTP Activation" installed on your computeur ?

[image: WCF Non-HTTP Activation]

Comment: Not sure. I have given up on using add reference in Visual Studio. Just doing everything manually instead and using ClientChannelFactory