# WCF With Generic types error

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, interface

i'm trying to implement WCF Service with generic interface
but im getting error.

at the "Web.config" file:

"The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value "xxx" is invalid according to its datatype 'clientContractType' - the Enumeration constraint failed"

is it possible to create generic on wcf service?

Tnx for help
Sry for newb question :)

endpoint:

Comment: Please show us some code/config

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906694/wcf-service-generic-methods